# How can I get more energy without spending coins?

Tags: wizards-unite

In the new Harry Potter Wizards Unite game, I have a current max energy of 75, but I've used it all up.

Is there a way to get more energy other than buying it with gold?

Will it regenerate over time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restore energy by entering inns found around the map. When you enter an inn, you cast a spell and a random meal (from a selection of 5) is chosen.  Some meals give more spell energy than others.  For instance, the Turkey dinner gives a lot of spell energy, while the every flavor beans give 2.

Not sure if the accuracy of the spell affects the choice or not, but I suspect that, like throwing a nice or a great throw in Pokemon Go, this is the case.

The attached image details the colors of the inns, why they are that color and the average amounts of spell energy you can get.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

According to [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2019/06/21/how-to-get-more-spell-energy-quickly-in-harry-potter-wizards-unite/#79e4ced557f4) and [Heavy](https://heavy.com/games/2019/06/harry-potter-wizards-unite-spell-energy/), there currently two ways to obtain spell energy without spending coins

1. By visiting in-game inns and greenhouses around your city. Based on what I have seen, the inns are generally in the same location as Pokestops in Pokémon Go.
2. By completing daily task assignments

While visiting inns, one of the guides also indicates to be aware of the color of the inn as well. Different colored inns provided different amounts of energy

> Players have noted that green inns typically have the most spell energy, with blue inns next. Pink inns have the least.

If you do wish to use coins, you can purchase both spell energy and increase your energy capacity

Comment: Thanks. This article also answered my next question. Can you increase the max energy. Yep, with microtransactions. Yippie!

Comment: Another thing to note, the S.O.S. package does not increase your max, it refills and allows it to go over your max (from what I understand)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the existing answers about Inns:

Spell energy is sometimes rewarded when visiting Portkeys.
It's also an award for some daily/achievement/mission tasks.